# How do I turn my "for" loop into a "for of" loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-of-loop

In javascript I'm trying to turn a for loop into a for/of loop, I've tried searching online for how to do for/of loops but I can't quite understand it.

I'm just wondering how I'd turn the for loop into a for/of loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
```

This is what studentCount is

```
studentCount = gradeXML.getElementsByTagName("student").length;
```

Comment: `for-of` is used to loop over iterable objects (such as an array). You appear to just be grabbing an integer count of the number of students, and thus have nothing to 'loop' over (as you only have a single value representing how many students there are). For your example, the standard `for-loop` is the better option, as you merely want to run a loop `x` number of times. If you had an array containing information on *each* of the students, then you could use `for-of`... but you would need to restructure your data (by removing `.length`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Please change the selector from `getElementsByTagName` to `querySelector[All]`, there is no `default HTML` tag with name of `student`. 
So I am assuming that the `student` is a `class`.

By default all the `DOM` selectors are `iterable`  (if it returns multiple elements).

**Example:**

```js
(function() {
    let students = document.querySelectorAll(".student");
    for (const st of students) {
        console.log(st.textContent);
    }
})()
```

```html
<div class="student"> Student 1 </div>
    <div class="student"> Student 2 </div>
    <div class="student"> Student 3 </div>
    <div class="student"> Student 4 </div>
    <div class="student"> Student 5 </div>
```